# how to get "leftover arguments" in optparse-applicative?

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, applicative

I am trying to use optparse-applicative.
How can I access arguments that are not options?
(From `prog --foo --bar=42 baz`, I want to get `["baz"]`)

All the the "high level" functions https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.11.0.2/docs/Options-Applicative-Extra.html
return `a` where I want `(a,[String])`.

There is some low-level function https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.11.0.2/docs/Options-Applicative-Common.html#v:runParser but I cannot call it directly because of its type. And indeed I do want to re-use all the plumbing that is in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.11.0.2/docs/src/Options-Applicative-Extra.html#execParser .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Positional arguments are part of the parser specification. They are not returned separately by the function that runs the parser. The functions `argument` and `strArgument` can be used to add a parser for a positional argument to the specification.

Comment: What if you need a variable amount of arguments grouped together (as in a number of unix commands that take a list of file names at the end)?

Comment: Parsers are an instance of `Applicative`, so you can use functions like `many` or `some` to allow a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Those were the functions I was missing.